# Discord.JS token ban function not working properly when trying to run the command in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, token

Ok so i was trying to create a discord bot, with ban commands but then this happened

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogAHf.png

Here is my code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ceGo.png

How do i fix this?

Comment: This is what happens when i do that
https://ibb.co/GdgG12W

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the question, do not use links to images on external sites.

Comment: module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "This command bans people",
    execute(message, args)}

    if(message.member.roles.cache.has('923203237019004958')){
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(member){
            const memberTarger = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
            memberTarger.ban();
            message.channel.send("User has been banned from the paper bag")
        } else {
            message.channel.send("You don't have the sufficent permissions to run this command")
        }
    }

Comment: "*paste code into the question*", this is the comment section... Use the `edit` button on your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "This command bans people",
    execute(message, args) {

        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('923203237019004958')) {
            const member = message.mentions.members.first();
            if(member) {
                const memberTarger = message.guild.members.cache.get(member.id);
                memberTarger.ban();
                message.channel.send("User has been banned from the paper bag");
            }
            else {
                message.channel.send("You don't have the sufficent permissions to run this command")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

There was a closing bracket } next to the `execute(message, args)` but it should be an opening bracket {